# @yield('content') on laravel not working just plain white text

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3, laravel-blade, highlight, yield

I've already installed Laravel Blade Highlighter..

@yield @section @endsection is not working, just a plain white text..

My views are working properly.. I can browser them okay..

Here's my code:

web.php:

```
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/services', 'PagesController@services');
```

pagesController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('pages.index');;
    }

    public function about(){
        return view('pages.about');
    }

    public function services(){
        return view('pages.services');
    }

}
```

app.blade.php

```
<h1>This is the laravel</h1>
@yield('content')
```

index.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Welcome to Laravel</h1>
    <p>this is a content</p>
@endsection
```

Comment: And app.blade.php is in the layouts directory, right?

Comment: You need to change `index.php` to `index.blade.php` then you need to change `storage` permissions to php can write there.

Comment: Yes it works thanks! And I should close all tabs on sublime text so I could see the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is I should close all open tab on my sublime text..

And index.php, about.php and services.php should be index.blade.php, about.blade.php and services.blade.php